# -webkit-transform with different transition times for rotateX and rotateY

Tags: jquery, html, css, webkit

Is it possible for both rotateX and rotateY in CSS3 to have different transition times. I realise that you use -webkit-transition to set a time but, as you can see below, it seems impossible to set different transition times for both. You can only set it for '-webkit-transform' itself.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <title>CSS3 Fun</title>
  <style>

    .panel {
        float: left;
        width: 500px;
        height: 200px;
        font-size: .8em;
        background: black;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;

        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg); 
        -webkit-perspective: 1000;
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }

    .panel.flip {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateX(180deg); 
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="panel">
    CONTENT
</div>
</body>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.js">       </script> -->
<script>
jQuery('.panel').toggle(function(){
    jQuery(this).addClass('flip');
},function(){
    jQuery(this).removeClass('flip');
});
</script>
</html>
```

Note: Probably stating the obvious, but the above will only work in webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari).

Thanks for all your help.

Cheers, Matthew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not as elegant, but you can use CSS animations rather than transitions.

```
.panel.flip {
    -webkit-animation: flip-panel 1s;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateX(180deg);
}

@-webkit-keyframes flip-panel {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateX(90deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateX(180deg);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to remove `-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;`.